# como pongo lineas entre los items de un gridview

Tags: android-studio, gridview

estoy haciendo una especie de calendario e hice un gridview para que muestre los dias de la semana arriba, los puedo mostrar bien pero no se muestra ninguna linea que los divida y me gustaria ponerele una linea vertical entre cada uno o minimo que los encuadre

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/weekViewtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#DADA"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: estas usando un adapter personalizado?

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,daysofweek);`
@IgmerRodriguez

Comment: puedes usar un adapter personalizado para darle la forma que desea

Comment: si hice un adapter personalizado y use fondos distintos para hacer las lineas aun que no me termina de convencer como queda voy a ir probando gracias!